# malware(2296) in Temp folder

Tags: virus, virus-removal

I found a file name malware(2296).tmp in my temp folder. Can I delete this? Is it really a malware? It's been created over a year ago and I'm not sure how. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I regularly delete all files in my temp folder without issue.

Answer (score 1):

the file itself is unlikely to be malware, the most likely thing is that the file itself is a data-cache the malware was using for unknown purposes. It probably stores data the piece of malware either needed to "remember", or that it wanted to store in one location to send elsewhere later.

It is possible that an antivirus program killed the malware before it could delete the temporary data-cache, and thus you were left with the file. It is also equally possible that a minor technical glitch stopped it deleting the file, and the program "forgot" about it, and may still be active on the computer.

If i were you, i would do a full scan of the PC with an accredited antivirus software, preferably from a known to be safe and clean LiveCD and not the potentially infected OS.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not necessarily malware, this folder could have been used for the malware to load itself into your memory and other locations. I would recommend you to use [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download) to clean all your temporary files and [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/) to scan your system for malware.

Good luck!